# Django - disable duplicates in related set

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-2.1

There is a class `Order`, `SubOrder` and class `Product`. I want to make sure that no `Order` object will contain multiple `SubOrder` objects with the same `Product` object.

```
class Order(TimeStampedModel):
    ....

class SubOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey('orders.Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='suborders')
    product = models.ForeignKey('products.Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Počet')
```

So if there were 3 products - **A, B, C**

I don't want allow one `Order` object to have multiple `SubOrders` with the same `Product`. 
For example `Order[Suborder[A,12],Suborder[B,12],Suborder[B,5]]` should raise `ValidationError` because there are two `SubOrders` with the same `Product` **B**.

Is it possible to do that on the `model` or `database` layer?

**EDIT**

I tried this:

```
def clean(self):
    neighbour_suborders = self.order.suborders.filter(product=self.product)
    if self.pk:
        neighbour_suborders = neighbour_suborders.exclude(pk=self.pk)
    if neighbour_suborders.exists():
        raise ValidationError("Takýto produkt už v objednávke existuje!")
```

But it allows to create such order in Django admin.

Comment: Yes you can change Foreignkey with OneToOne fleld for product field.

Comment: A OneToOne relationship would prevent saving more than one suborder per order, which is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: I have updated, you have to use OnetoOne on product field, which means one product will be only having one entry in this table. Order field remains same as Foreignkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A unique constraint for order and product prevents saving more than one suborder for the same order and the same product:

```
class SubOrder(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('order', 'product',)
```